# Create new excel file using VBA in a Word Doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a new excel workbook where I'll put in data from an array I generated.

I keep getting this error, "Run-time error '424': Object Required"

I'm using code that I found online at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/create-a-workbook).

```
Set NewBook = app.Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
.Title = "Cable Numbers"
.Subject = "Documentation"
'parentFld is a file path where a previous document is being used
.SaveAs FileName:=parentFld & "CableNumbers.xlsx"
End With
```

The workbook isn't even being created. How can I create a new workbook if my macro is in a word document?

Here's some more of my code for reference:

```
Function SelectFile()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    ' show the file picker dialog box
    If .Show <> 0 Then
        SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
End Function

Function PrintValue(PrintRow As Long, PrintCol As Long, ArrayName As ArrayList, ArrayIndex As Long)
'Probably doesn't work. I want to print the value from the array into a spreadsheet's first column

app.ActiveSheet.Cells(PrintRow, PrintCol) = ArrayName(ArrayIndex)

End Function

Sub getFirstColumn()

' Gets the first column of all tables in a given file

'Declare variables
Dim wbName As String
Dim TableCount, tableNum As Integer 'This is the number of tables in thedocument minus 1 since loop starts at 0'
Dim dataCell As Variant
Dim printRowCounter, indexCounter As Long
Dim docO As Document
Dim app As Object

Dim fileObj, fldObj As New FileSystemObject
Set fileObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

printRowCounter = 1
indexCounter = 0
'Choose a file to get data from. This is a ms Word doc
MsgBox "Choose a workbook file. This file must have a table in it."
wbPath = SelectFile()
wbName = CStr(fileObj.GetFileName(wbPath))
Documents(wbName).Activate
parentFld = fldObj.GetParentFolderName(wbPath)

TableCount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
Dim firstColArray As ArrayList
Set firstColArray = New ArrayList

For tableNum = 1 To TableCount
RowCount = ActiveDocument.Tables(tableNum).Range.Rows.Count
    For rowNum = 1 To RowCount
        ActiveDocument.Tables(tableNum).Cell(Row:=rowNum, Column:=1).Select  'For testing purposes
        cellContent = ActiveDocument.Tables(tableNum).Cell(Row:=rowNum, Column:=1)
        If cellContent = "" Then
            GoTo Skip
        Else
            dataCell = ActiveDocument.Tables(tableNum).Cell(Row:=rowNum, Column:=1)
            firstColArray.Add dataCell
        End If
Skip:
    Next rowNum
Next tableNum

MsgBox "All data has been collected." & vbNewLine & "Creating an excel file..."

'Creating an excel workbook and inputing data
Set NewBook = app.Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
.Title = "Numbers"
.Subject = "Documentation"
.SaveAs.Close FileName:=parentFld & "\Numbers.xlsx"
End With

app.Workbooks("Numbers.xlsx").Activate
For Each thing In firstColArray
    app.ActiveSheet.Cells(printRowCounter, 1) = firstColArray(indexCounter)
    printRowCounter = printRowCounter + 1
    indexCounter = indexCounter + 1
Next thing

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to create (or get) an Excel instance first. `Dim app As Object`, `Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, `Set NewBook = app.Workbooks.Add`.

Comment: .. and then frame all of your Excel calls as references to that Excel instance.  So `Workbooks.Add` becomes `app.Workbooks.Add`

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for your response. That seemed to resolve part of the issue, but I'm getting an error "Run-time error '1004': Cannot access 'AllSales.xlsx'. The file is still not created in the folder I specified.

Comment: You didn't specify a folder though, just a filename.

Comment: @BigBen Whoops you're right. I meant to establish a file path. How would I do that in this With loop?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your revised code?

Comment: @BigBen complete

Comment: What is `parentFld`? A `String`? Probably missing an `Application.PathSeparator` between the folder name and the filename.

Comment: @BigBen I was missing a \. I'm having a lot of issues trying to open the excel file to trouble shoot. Either an error for "Sorry we can't find Cab;eNumbers.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?' Also when I try and open the excel file from the file explorer. it says the file is already open and being edited by me.  Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Add `.Close` after `.SaveAs`.

Comment: @BigBen I'm getting the same Run-time error '424': Object Required error code when I put .SaveAs.Close FileName:=parentFld & "\CableNumbers2.xlsx"

Comment: Could you kindly post the complete code (from `Sub ...` to `End Sub`? There are many issues. `app` is kind of misleading, `xlApp` is a better option. I prefer adding the `FileFormat` parameter when doing a `SaveAs`: `.SaveAs ..., FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`. Like `SaveAs`, `Open` usually needs a path: `app.Workbooks.Open(parentFld & "CableNumbers.xlsx")`. But why would you need to open it in the first place, when you have already created a reference to it (`NewBook`)? Since you have opted for a `For Each...Next` loop why don't you use `= thing` instead of `= firstColArray(indexCounter)`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Code Updated. Thanks for your advice. I'm new to VBA

Answer (score 2):

```
Function FileExists(FName As String) As Boolean
' Returns True if the file FName exists, else False
Dim fs
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExists = fs.FileExists(FName)
    Set fs = Nothing
End Function


Set oxlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelStatus = FileExists(CStr(newExcelPath))
If excelStatus = True Then  'If the file exists, append to it
        excelStatus = "append"
ElseIf excelStatus = False Then  'If the file doesn't exist, create a new file
        excelStatus = "new"
        Set NewBook = oxlApp.Workbooks.Add
        With NewBook
        .Title = "Cable Numbers"
        .Subject = "Documentation"
        .SaveAs fileName:=newExcelPath
        .Close
        End With
End If

Set oxlWbk = oxlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=newExcelPath)   'Open
If excelStatus = "new" Then  'If the excel is new, select the first sheet
    'oxlWbk.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
ElseIf excelStatus = "append" Then  'If the excel is old, add a sheet to the end and select it
    oxlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=oxlWbk.Sheets(oxlWbk.Sheets.Count)
    oxlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(oxlWbk.Sheets.Count).Select
End If
```